# Jquery tab disabling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery tab. I want to disable the tabs when the form is in edit mode.
Iam using a query string `id` for this and `type` for identifying the tab

According to the value of id the tab is disabled. Iam using following code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var id = getQuerystring("Id");
        if (isNaN(id)) {
            var inx = getQuerystring("type");
            if (isNaN(inx))
                inx = 1;
            inx = inx - 1;
            $('#tabs').tabs();
        }
        else {
            var inx = getQuerystring("type");
            if (isNaN(inx))
                inx = 1;
            inx = inx - 1;
            $('#tabs').tabs();
            $('#tabs').tabs('select', inx);
            if (!isNaN(id)) {
                for (var cnt = 0; cnt < 6; cnt++) {
                    $('#tabs').tabs('disable', cnt);
                    if (cnt == (inx)) {
                        $('#tabs').tabs();
                        $('#tabs').tabs('select', cnt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (inx == 0)
            LoadIframePage('CashReceipt.aspx?type1=1');
        else if (inx == 1)
            LoadIframePage('CashPayment.aspx?type1=2');
        else if (inx == 2)
            LoadIframePage('BankDeposit.aspx?type1=3');
        else if (inx == 3)
            LoadIframePage('BankWithDrawal.aspx?type1=4');
        else if (inx == 4)
            LoadIframePage('Journal.aspx?type1=5');


    });






 <div id="tabs" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100%; height: 100%; visibility:hidden" onload="SelectaTab(2);">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="cr" href="#fragment" onclick="LoadIframePage('CashReceipt.aspx?type1=1')"><span>Cash Receipt</span></a></li>
                    <li><a id="cp" href="#fragment" onclick="LoadIframePage('CashPayment.aspx?type1=2')"
    ><span>Cash Payment</span></a></li>
                    <li><a id="br" href="#fragment" onclick="LoadIframePage('BankDeposit.aspx?type1=3')"><span>Bank Receipt</span></a></li>
                    <li><a id="bw" href="#fragment" onclick="LoadIframePage('BankWithDrawal.aspx?type1=4')"><span>Bank Payment</span></a></li>
                    <li><a id="jr" href="#fragment" onclick="LoadIframePage('Journal.aspx?type1=5')"><span>Journal</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="fragment" style="width: 100%; height: 90%">
                    <iframe  style="width: 98%; height: 100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="ifrforms" onload="test">

                    </iframe>
                </div>

            </div>
```

My pblm is that tabs are disabled . but while clicking on the tab the page is redirected and that page is loaded...How can i solve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the function LoadIframePage defined?  Could you put an if statement in there like so:

```
 if( $('#tabs').attr("disabled") ) {
     return;  // do nothing
 } else {
     // carry on...
 }
```

Comment: LoadiframePage is used to change the url of iframe on tab click. And i tried the above code. But result is as usuall

Comment: Are you sure your tabs are really being disabled?  Try $('#tabs').attr("disabled",true);  Also, I'd suggest putting a class attribute on all of the tabs and calling disabled on them too.  Typically, a click event can't fire on a disabled element but sometimes can fire if only the parent is disabled.